# A little help understanding closures?

Tags: javascript, closures

In the Flatiron lesson I'm doing on closures, there is the following example:

```js
function retailPriceMaker(manufacturePrice) {
  return function(marketMultiplier) {
    return marketMultiplier * manufacturePrice;
  };
}

const retailPriceForNine = retailPriceMaker(9);

retailPriceForNine(2);
// 18
```

The lesson of course talks about how when the function inside `retailPriceMaker` is declared, the closure has access to (closure over) the variables in its scope, i.e., `manufacturePrice`, and retains it even when it's called, later.

I do understand this, as much as it makes my brain hurt.

One way that makes it a lot simpler for me is to think of it this way:

---

**`retailPriceMaker(9)` returns the following function:**

```js
function(marketMultiplier) {
    return marketMultiplier * 9; 
  };
```

---

Where the fact that there was ever a variable called `manufacturePrice` *does not matter* and might as well be erased from the returned function's history books.

The idea that a closure "writes in" the values that are passed to it, rather than thinking of the variables/arguments being referenced in seeming absentia, is a LOT easier to wrap my head around.

So **my question is**: is this a valid way to think of closures, or am I missing something? It does seem a little too simple, and I would assume that if my explanation were completely valid:

1. Closures would indeed be taught this way
2. The JavaScript console would show the "filled in" function when you call the returned function:

```js
function retailPriceMaker(manufacturePrice) {
  return function(marketMultiplier) {
    return marketMultiplier * manufacturePrice;
  };
}

const retailPriceForNine = retailPriceMaker(9);

retailPriceForNine;
// ƒ (marketMultiplier) {
//    return marketMultiplier * 9;
//  }
```

So, what, if anything, am I missing? Or have I just turned everyone's world upside down? (highly, completely unlikely)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: As another resource I've written an article explaining closures - https://medium.com/@r.henry1989/javascript-what-is-closure-81c0d2b74916

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is too simple. Sure, in many cases the closed-over variable is a constant, and might as well be filled in. But in general, you need to consider that it is closing over a *mutable* variable:

```
var count = 0;
function increment() { // yes, this is a closure as well - `count` is in its scope
  count++;
}

console.log(count);
increment();
console.log(count);
increment();
console.log(count);
```

Comment: "But in general, you need to close over a **mutable** variable" - I suppose that's your personal preference. Closures over immutables are fine and I see them a lot.

Comment: @AlexYu Sorry for the incomprehensible phrasing, edited. It was never my intention to advise using mutable variables...

Answer (score 0):

Closures are in fact very simple concept with powerful consequences.

I'm not an historian of programming languages and cannot provide comparative analysis in different languages but I suppose they are everywhere almost the same as was defined in Scheme specification in 1975 by Sussman and Steel.

So how do we can describe closure in most simple way?

## Very simple explanation from interpreter point (although maybe not "mathemathically" correct)

It's just a trick that allows to "break the rules" of variable lifecycle.

Let's look at your example:

```
/* 1. Each function have an own "namespace" where variables lives
   2. After `return` from a function it's namespace *must* be destroyed in "normal" cases 
      and every value *must* be deallocated */
function retailPriceMaker(manufacturePrice) { 
    /* 3. manufacturePrice - *must* be deallocated 
     after return from retailPriceMaker */
    return function(marketMultiplier) { 
    /* 4. But closures allows to "break" this rule 
          and languages that supports closures 
          do not deallocate "closed" values */
      return marketMultiplier * manufacturePrice; 
    };
    /* 5. manufacturePrice value here remains closed 
         and not deallocated after return */
}
```

Everything becames much more simpler if you think about allocations and deallocations.

Just note that:

1. Without closures interpreter **must** destroy value after return from function
2. Closures allows to "break" this rule. "Closed" values are not destroyed after return
3. This "trick" is very simple itself but very powerful